# Is it possible to add a contact to buddy list with out subscribe request?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, meebo

I have developed MSN, Yahoo and Facebook Instant Messaging using ejabberd, strophe and transports. Every time when legacy user register him self with his credentials to transport, he has to authorize bunch of subscribe requests. Is it possible to avoid this process.  I am wondering how meebo  adding contacts to respective buddy lists without asking any subscribe requests.

Thanks,
Sathi

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Meebo automatically confirms the subscription requests without the user knowing, since they can (correctly) infer this is the user's intent when interfacing with a social network that does not have asynchronous connections.

Just have your own code automatically respond to ask='subscribe' requests from users behind the gateway to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Jack, for your reply. I always get type="subscribe" from ejabberd server. Is there any way to send some message to server for getting different subscribe requests. Thanks, --sathi